# AMD64 Assembler. Load 128bit from memory (indirect addressing) to xmm register

Tags: assembly, mov, sse

The value of the `rsi-register` points to some space in memory and I want to load the first 128 bit into an arbitrary xmm register. I tried `movdqa %rsi, %xmm0`, but %rsi is a `invalid operand for instruction`. I think I have to convert it to a double quadword but I was not able to find such a command.

How can I use 64bit registers as operand of the movdqa command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax in gnu assembler is

```
movdqa (%rsi), %xmm0
```